# Apply MVC User Based and Role Based Authorization to View and Action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authorization

Within MVC 3, I am trying to figure out how to apply both role and user based security properly (and following best practices) to one of my views.  I have a view that lists details for any given "member" (aka user).  I want all members to be able to view the details for any other member, but if the member is viewing their own detail, I want them to be able to edit their own details.  Also, a site administrator should be able to edit any members detail.

For your reference, my site is configured as follows:

- I created my own authentication provider (**not** using or overriding the SqlMembershipProvider) that is very simple and uses forms authentication.
- I overrode the default RoleProvider to implement my own methods for IsUserInRole and GetRolesForUser.  Both methods are working fine.
- All of my views use "flattened" view models that map from my concrete entities.
- My Detail view is used for **both** displaying information **and** editing information.  A flag (called IsInEditMode) is used (and passed into a custom HtmlHelper) to determine whether or not to simply display the data or provide an editor field. I would like to keep this single view.

Here are my specific requirements.  I am listing them all in this question, as I believe that the correct answer will/should address all these concerns (let me know if this is incorrect):

1. Members should be able to view any other member's detail.
2. Members should be able to edit **most** of their own detail, but some aspects of their detail should only be editable by a site administrator (e.g. **Status** of approved or provisional)
3. Members that belong to the "Site Administrator" role can edit everything.
4. The "Edit" button within the detail view needs to be displyed only based on the member's role (as Site Administrator) or verification of the users id/name with their login credentials.
5. The controller HttpPost Edit action needs to verify that the user is approved to edit.  I know I can decorate the action with a role like `[Authorize(Roles = "Site Administrator")]`, but I don't know how to implement an `OR UserBeingEdited == LoggedInUser` attribute.
6. In addition, I want to prevent malicious edits such as a user "fiddling" with the user ID value returned as well as XSS and CSRF attacks.

Below is my applicable code (that doesn't have any security applied) for the controller and view.  Any suggestions are appreciated!

**MemberController.cs Edit Action sippet:**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
//TODO: Find out how to allow only "Site Administrator" roles OR the logged in user to edit their own information
public ActionResult Edit(MemberDetailViewModel memberDetailViewModel)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //TODO: Find out how to prevent member ID tampering (including XSS and CSRF attacks)
    var updatedMember = _memberServices.Find(memberDetailViewModel.MemberId);
    Mapper.Map(memberDetailViewModel, updatedMember);
    _memberRepository.InsertOrUpdate(updatedMember);
    return RedirectToAction("Detail", new {id = memberDetailViewModel.MemberId});
  }
  else
  {
    return View("Detail", _memberQueries.GetMemberDetailViewModel(memberDetailViewModel.MemberId, isInEditMode:true));
  }
}
```

**Member Detail.cshtml View** (only relevant parts included):

```
@model MyApp.Web.Areas.Members.Models.MemberDetailViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Member", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "memberDetailForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  <fieldset id="pageTitle">
    <h2>
      <!-- TODO: Only allow editing by "Site Administrators" or the verified logged in user -->
      @if (Model.IsInEditMode)
      {
        @:Editing @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName
        <a class="button" href="@Url.Action("Detail", new { id = @Model.MemberId })">Cancel</a>
        <input class="button" type="submit" value="Save" />
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => Model.MemberId)
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      }
      else
      {
        @:Details for @Model.FirstName @Model.LastName
        <a class="button" href="@Url.Action("Edit", new { id = @Model.MemberId })">Edit</a>
      }
    </h2>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
      <legend>Basic Information</legend>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td class="label">
            First Name:
          </td>
          <td class="field">
            @Html.DisplayOrEditorFor(x => Model.FirstName, Model.IsInEditMode)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.FirstName)
          </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Other properties omitted -->
        <tr>
          <td class="label">
            Status: 
          </td>
          <td class="field">
            <!-- TODO: This status field should only be editable by "Site Administrator", not the user -->
            @Html.DisplayOrEditorDropDownListFor(x => Model.StatusId, Model.StatusList, Model.IsInEditMode)
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
  </fieldset>
}
```

If needed to better understand my view, here is a sample of my **DisplayOrEditorFor** custom HtmlHelper function:

```
public static MvcHtmlString DisplayOrEditorFor<TModel, TValue>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression, bool isInEditMode)
{
  return isInEditMode ? System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor(htmlHelper, expression) : System.Web.Mvc.Html.DisplayExtensions.DisplayFor(htmlHelper, expression);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution in your case is to only set IsInEditMode when the id of the edited user == the id of the current user, or the user is an administrator.

You don't want to use anything other than a generic Authorize attribute, because all registered users can access the page, thus you don't want or need additional auth on the page itself, just on the fields, and those fields are controlled by your IsInEditMode boolean.

You would also do a test on the "Edit" link to see if it's the current user or admin, as well as special tests for fields where only the admin can edit.

So, you would do something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayOrEditorDropDownListFor(x => Model.StatusId, Model.StatusList, 
     Model.IsInEditMode && User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
```

Whether it's in Edit mode will be set in the controller.  It will only allow EditMode to be set true if it's the current user or an admin.

Comment: thanks.  That makes sense.  Two questions for you... What is the best method to verify that the information I receive from the users cookie is valid (prevent fiddling with the UserId value) and how do I achieve requirement #6 (XSS and CSRF attacks).  I always hear to never trust user supplied data (including form and cookie values), so what is best practice to verify this information within my controller action?

Comment: @bmccleary - What cookie values?  The solution I gave you did not include anything cookie related.  XSS is solved by encoding any user supplied input.  CSRF is solved by using the AntiForgeryToken helper.  You do have to make sure that the Edit action method validates that the user is an admin or the current user.  You can deal with that simply by redirecting back to display if they're not, or simply just displaying even though it's the edit method.

Comment: @bmccleary - Although this solution works, I wonder if this is the correct attitude. With this solution the code that related to EditMode is spread on two places (for each action) - in the Controller and in the View. A better option, IMHO, is to place the code that controls the EditMode in a dedicated class that by some magic route the user to the correct Controller action based on it's role. Think what will happen to the condition that you send to the HtmlHelper if your requirements will complicate.

Comment: @Ikaso - Certainly, I agree this can get complicated.  However, given the requirements of the question, I felt a relatively simple conditional block was the least amount of change.  My preferred solution is to simply return an administrative view that has the edit links if the IsAdmin is true.  I think having business logic in the routing system is probably not the right way to do it.

Comment: @MystereMan - got your point. I am just wondering what the right solution in case you have more than 2 roles. Maybe there should be a notion of a sub-action: the main action simply checks the user is authorized for the view. It delegates the operation to a sub-action that checks the user role and then returns the correct view to the user.

Comment: @lkaso, thanks for the input, and yes, I did implement a solution that determines the IsInEditMode value from a service class outside of the controller, but overall, it is similar to what Mystere Man provided.